# How to put a table and a matrix side by side on Latex

Tags: positioning

I don't know how to put a table and a matrix side by side. If you have to know the data on the table is just the entries of the matrix that I want to put at the right side of the table.

Comment: Multiple possibilities are available here since we don't have much info about the elements. A simple option: In the preamble `\usepackage{amsmath}` and in your document:
`\[
\begin{array}{cc}
\hline
\text{header 1} & \text{header 2} \\
\hline
1 & 2 \\
3 & 4 \\
\hline
\end{array}\qquad
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 \\
3 & 4 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\]`

Comment: Enclose it in two successive minipages.

Answer (score 1):

A `tabular` and `array` have their vertical anchor centered. So you can place them next to one another just like you do regular characters/symbols:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  \begin{tabular}{*{4}{c}}
    \toprule
    A & B & C & D \\
    \midrule
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
    5 & 6 & 7 & 8 \\
    9 & 10 & 11 & 12 \\
    13 & 14 & 15 & 16 \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
  \qquad
  $\left[\begin{array}{*{4}{c}}
    A & B & C & D \\
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
    5 & 6 & 7 & 8 \\
    9 & 10 & 11 & 12 \\
    13 & 14 & 15 & 16
  \end{array}\right]
  $
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Of course, other alignments are also possible.